# NGINX conditionally turn on/off proxy_intercept_errors

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-500

I got 2 clients that may send same HTTP request to Server through nginx proxy.

one is **browser** the other is **my own program**, the difference is request send from **my own program** have custom HEADER `my-header=me`

My goal is: 
if any request leads to a `http:500` response of the Server, I would like the **browser** to show an Error page and **my own program** log the original response from server which contains Exception stacks.

With nginx `proxy_intercept_errors=on` and  `error_page 500 /500.html` I can navigate to error page for **browser requests**, but I will also log this html page in **my own program** which I don't want.

I have search a while for solutions such as `conditional proxy_intercept_errors` or `return/rewrite original response before proxy` but got no answers.

How I achieve my goal by nginx settings?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use Nginx `map` to detect the header value to create a switch.

Then you should be able to use `rewrite` to route accordingly to the desired `location` block

```
map $http_my_header $intercept {
  default "intercept_on";
  me "intercept_off";
}
server {
  listen 80 default_server;

  location /test {
    rewrite /test /$intercept last;
  }

  location /intercept_on {
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    default_type text/plain;
    echo "Intercept errors is: On";
  }

  location /intercept_off {
    proxy_intercept_errors off;
    default_type text/plain;
    echo "Intercept errors is: Off";
  }
}
```

Beside `rewrite`, you could also use `try_files` with `@` named location but don't think it was meant for this.