# Nginx as reverse proxy: How to display a custom error page for upstream errors, UNLESS the upstream says not to?

Tags: http, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have an Nginx instance running as a reverse proxy. When the upstream server does not respond, I send a custom error page for the 502 response code. When the upstream server sends an error page, that gets forwarded to the client, and I'd like to show a custom error page in that case as well.

If I wanted to replace all of the error pages from the upstream server, I would set [`proxy_intercept_errors on`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors) to show a custom page on each of them. However, there are cases where I'd like to return the actual response that the upstream server sent: for example, for API endpoints, or if the error page has specific user-readable text relating to the issue.

In the config, a single `server` is proxying multiple applications that are behind their own proxy setups and their own rules for forwarding requests around, so I can't just specify this per each `location`, and it has to work for any URL that matches a `server`.

Because of this, I would like to send the custom error page, *unless* the upstream application says not to. The easiest way to do this would be with a custom HTTP header. There is a similar question about [doing this depending on the *request* headers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44402862/5936187). Is there a way to do this depending on the *response* headers?

(It appears that [somebody else already had this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68558912/5936187) and their conclusion was that it was impossible with plain Nginx. If that's true, I would be interested in some other ideas on how to solve this, possibly using OpenResty like that person did.)

So far I have tried using OpenResty to do this, but it doesn't seem compatible with `proxy_pass`: the response that the Lua code generates seems to overwrite the response from the upstream server.

Here's the `location` block I tried to use:

```
location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:65000;

        content_by_lua_block{
          ngx.say("This seems to overwrite the content from the proxy?!")
        }        

        body_filter_by_lua_block {
          ngx.arg[1]="Truncated by code!"
          ngx.arg[2]=false
          if ngx.status >= 400 then
            if not ngx.resp.get_headers()["X-Verbatim"] then
              local file = io.open('/usr/share/nginx/error.html', 'w')
              local html_text = file:read("*a")
              ngx.arg[1] = html_text
              ngx.arg[2] = true
              return
            end
          end
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that you can send custom error pages based on the response header since the only way, as per my knowledge, you could achieve that was using either `map` or `if` directive. Since both of these directives don't have scope after the request is sent to the upstream, they can't possibly read the response header.

However, you could do this using openresty and writing your own lua script. The lua script to do such a thing would look something like:

```
location / {
  body_filter_by_lua '
     if ngx.resp.get_headers()["Cust-Resp-Header"] then
         local file = io.open('/path/to/file.html', 'r')
         local html_text = f:read()
         ngx.arg[1] = html_text
         ngx.arg[2] = true
         return
     end
  ';

  #
  .
  .
  .
}
```

You could also use `body_filter_by_lua_block` (you could enclose your lua code inside curly brances instead writing as nginx string) or `body_filter_by_lua_file` (you could write your lua code in a separate file and provide the file path).

You can find how to get started with openresty [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-openresty-web-framework-for-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04).

**P.S.:** You can read the response status code from the upstream using `ngx.status`. As far as reading the body is concerned, the variable `ngx.arg[1]` would contain the response body after the response from the upstream which we're modifying here. You can save the `ngx.arg[1]` in a local variable and try to read the error message from that using some regexp and appending later in the `html_text` variable. Hope that helps.

**Edit 1:** Pasting here a sample working lua block inside a location block with proxy_pass:

```
location /hello {
    proxy_pass          http://localhost:3102/;
    body_filter_by_lua_block {
        if ngx.resp.get_headers()["erratic"] == "true" then                          
                ngx.arg[1] = "<html><body>Hi</body></html>"
        end
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:** You can't use `content_by_lua_block` with `proxy_pass` or else your proxy wouldn't work. Your location block should look like this (assuming `X-Verbatim` header is set to "false" (a string) if you've to override the error response body from the upstream).

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:65000;        

    body_filter_by_lua_block {
      if ngx.status >= 400 then
        if ngx.resp.get_headers()["X-Verbatim"] == "false" then
          local file = io.open('/usr/share/nginx/error.html', 'w')
          local html_text = file:read("*a")
          ngx.arg[1] = html_text
          ngx.arg[2] = true
        end
      end
}
```

}

Comment: This is almost exactly what I wanted, but I also need to be able to load the custom page from a file, and include some details of what the error was. I was doing it with SSI previously, how can you do it within Lua? (Also, I can't really find a reference to OpenResty directives and language features, can you give me a pointer to those?)

Comment: @Danya02 I've made some edits to the answer. The script shows how you can read the contents of a file. I've added a DO link where you can get yourself started on openresty and lua.

Comment: I've managed to install and run OpenResty, but it appears that whenever any Lua block is present in the `location` configuration, the normal proxy operation is overridden: if I add a `body_filter_by_lua_block`, even an empty one, the server only ever serves empty replies, and if I add a `content_by_lua_block` with an `ngx.say`, then that's the only thing I receive on any request.

Comment: @Danya02 Can you please paste any of your location blocks?

Comment: @Danya02 `content_by_lua_block` doesn't work with proxy_pass. FYI

Comment: I added the `location` block to the question.

Comment: @Danya02 Updated the answer correcting your `location` block. It's working for me.

Comment: Indeed, it does work. I was having trouble because the path I set didn't exist. I didn't catch it immediately because it was a Docker container, and I only now enabled logging properly. But it's working now, thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat opposite of the requested but I think it can fit anyway. It shows the original response *unless upstream says what to show*.

There is a set of [X-Accel](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/) custom headers that are evaluated from upstream responses. `X-Accel-Redirect` allows you to tell NGINX to process another location instead. Below is an example how it can be used.

This is a Flask application that gives 50/50 normal responses and errors. The error responses come with `X-Accel-Redirect` header, instructing NGINX to reply with contents from the `@error_page` location.

```py
import flask
import random

application = flask.Flask(__name__)


@application.route("/")
def main():
    if random.randint(0, 1):
        resp = flask.Response("Random error")  # upstream body contents
        resp.headers['X-Accel-Redirect'] = '@error_page'  # the header
        return resp
    else:
        return "Normal response"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run("0.0.0.0", port=4000)
```

And here is a NGINX config for that:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
  }
  location @error_page {
    return 200 "That was an error";
  }
}
```

Putting these together you will see either "Normal response" from the app, or "That was an error" from the `@error_page` location ("Random error" will be suppressed). With this setup you can create a number of various locations (`@error_502`, `@foo`, `@etc`) for various errors and make your application to use them.

Comment: This would probably work very well if you were designing an application from the ground up to use this, but I'm dealing with applications that were built before me and I have only minimal control over -- or in some cases none at all.